# Level of Mathematics required to be successful PhD level

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics, mathematical-economics

I am hoping to study Economics at the graduate level but my current math is lacking.

I have Calculus II, Linear Alebra I, Stats 1-3 and Econometrics under my belt.

I am to take Linear II, and Calculus III soon.

After that, I will study Real Analysis, Multivariable Calculus, and Stochastic processes.

I would very much like to study Theory, in Macroeconomics, and in Econometrics.

What level of mathematics should I be striving for?

Comment: Do I read the second to last sentence correctly in that you are interested in macroecometric theory and econometric theory?

Answer (score 2):

In economics the rule is that more math is always better irrespective of the field.

What is contained in calculus I and II and so on is not standardized between different universities so I will just list topics that are important to master.

For macroeconomic theory you should have excellent command of:

- Differential equations
- Dynamic optimization (also discrete)
- Calculus of variations
- Topology and separation

For econometrics theory:

- Linear algebra
- Vector and matrix calculus
- Probability theory

Especially for theory (as opposed to applied stuff) you want to go for as much math in this areas as possible. However, general rule in economics is that you will never regret taking too much math but you might regret taking too little.

Answer (score 0):

If you take those classes and understand them all then you will be fine. Even in very good graduate programs, people come in with a wide variety of math backgrounds and your starting math ability is not a very strong predictor of success after the first year. You need to understand the basic tools and have the 'mathematical maturity' to be comfortable picking up the other tools and techniques and you go along.

Understand multivariable calculus and linear algebra very well. Take a good real analysis class. Take a math stats course and a good probability course. After that, the returns to quickly diminish.